# Prolog Difference of 3 sets (S1\S2)\S3

Tags: list, prolog, set, set-difference

i have this working predicate for difference of 2 sets

```
difference([],Y,[]).
difference([X|R],Y,Z) :-
    member(X,Y),
    !,
    difference(R,Y,Z).
difference([X|R],Y,[X|Z]) :-
    difference(R,Y,Z).
```

But i would like to make similar thing for 3 sets and i can't figure it out
`difference(S1,S2,S3,result)` resulting in *(S1\S2)\S3*.

Comment: How about, `diff3(S1, S2, S3, R) :- difference(S1, S2, R1), difference(R1, S3, R).`?

Answer (score 1):

Well you basically already say it yourself: take the formula *(S1\S2)\S3*, substitute *S1\S2* by *T1* (a temporary), then the resulting formula is *T1\S3*.

So now put this into code:

```
difference(S1,S2,S3,Result) :-
    difference(S1,S2,T1),       %T1 = S1\S2
    difference(T1,S3,Result).   %Result = T1\S3=(S1\S2)\S3
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys... i still tried to fill it all into one big predicated and that confused me a lot.

Comment: @user3533469: well if there is still a problem, you can either [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34664852/edit) your question, or ask a new one.